# Generate values between non-linear points

Tags: r

I am aiming at smoothing out a curve with set values. To do this, I currently generate a vector between points in my curve like so:

```
> y.values <- c(values[1], mean(values[1:2]), values[2], ...)
```

This is not the fastest approach to say the least (and this snippet is just between two of the numbers!). I need a better way to generate a vector with known non-linear values and insert a value between each one, like so:

```
> values
[1] 1 2 4 6 9
> y.values <- magic(values)
> y.values
[1] 1 1.5 2 3 4 5 6 7.5 9
```

This question feels basic but I researched it and cannot seem to find a proper method for my non-linear vector, and any help is appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant way to do this but it works:

```
values <- c(1,2,4,6,9)

#lapply is used to create the mean values and those get merged
#in between your values inside the function

a <- c(unlist(lapply( 1:(length(values)-1 ), function(x) c(values[x],(values[x]+values[x+1])/2))),
       values[length(values)])
```

Output:

```
> a
[1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.5 9.0
```

Or as a function:

```
magic <- function(x) {
  c(unlist(lapply( 1:(length(x)-1 ), function(z) c(x[z],(x[z]+x[z+1])/2))),
         x[length(x)])
}

> magic(values)
[1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.5 9.0
```

Comment: This should work. I will try this on monday and come back to you.